# Decoding JsonWebKey from Azure Key Vault with Python

Tags: python, azure, key, rsa, azure-keyvault

I have a python script that retrieves a RSA private key from Azure Key Vault. Trying to serialize the key value gives:

> ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.

key_bytes looks like "b'\xb8w\xb7\xce{s\xf7\xa0\xce\xba\xf5#\x07\x8b?\x1d\xc9m..."

**Code:**

```
from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient, KeyVaultAuthentication
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

subscription_id = "xxx"
VAULT_URL = "xxx"
KEY_ID = "xxx"
KEY_VERSION = "xxx"

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = 'xxx',
    secret = 'xxx',
    tenant = 'xxx'
)

client = KeyVaultClient(credentials)

key_bundle = client.get_key(VAULT_URL,
                            KEY_ID,
                            KEY_VERSION)

key_bytes = key_bundle.key.n

p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    key_bytes,
    password='xxx',
    backend=default_backend()
    )
```

By loading the key from Blob storage in .p8 format the above key serialization works. Key vault requires the key to be saved in pem format.

I have tried different decodings etc but I haven't had success in decoding the bytes. Any help or tips to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** I was working with jwcrypto.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I've been struggling with JWKs the last few days. One thing that helped me was base64 encoding and decoding e and n (exponent and modulus of the key):
`base64.urlsafe_b64encode(n).decode()` What that does is it takes the ASCII-encoded (I believe) bytes n-value (b'...') and returns base64-encoded bytes then decoded into a string as that's what was required for my input.

- initial n value: `b'\xd4b\xd3/"Vi\x8b\xce\xaf...\xf1\xec\xcd`
- base64-encoded: `b'1GLTLyJWaYvOrwdje1O3...OvHszQ==`
- decoded: `'1GLTLyJWaYvOrwdje1O3...OvHszQ==` (note the '==' at the end, which is what you'd expect to see at the end of a private key)

Again, not sure if that helps.

[This](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt-devel/RSA-key-parameters.html) gives some context of parameters and from what I understand of [this](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/03/08/decryption-with-azure-key-vault.aspx) article, you can't actually get a private key out of a Key Vault, just a public one.

Comment: Thanks @EllaP, the links clarified things!